# Rails - Adding random numbers at the end of a URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this line to send a user to a specific page (www.uvestymeetings.com/) and I'm trying to have it generate a random number after the .com/ whenever a user submits. I'm thinking anywhere between 1-1000 is fine for now.

I know the random number on rails is : `<%= rand(5..30) %>`, but i'm not sure how to put it into this situation.

From controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @meeting.save
    format.html { redirect_to 'https://www.uvestymeetings.com/', notice: "Thanks for meeting!" }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @meeting }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @meeting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: will this mess with your member resource routes? meaning that the random number might be interpreted by rails routes as the resource id and that will likely fail?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you change this line.

```
format.html { redirect_to 'https://www.uvestymeetings.com/' + rand(1..1000).to_s, notice: "Thanks for meeting!" }
```

You dont need to use the ruby tags (`<%= %>`) in an `.rb` file.

Doing this will generate a link as such:
`https://www.uvestymeetings.com/580`

Answer (score 0):

code should be

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @meeting.save
    format.html { redirect_to "https://www.uvestymeetings.com/#{rand(1...1000)}", notice: "Thanks for meeting!" }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @meeting }
  else
   format.html { render action: 'new' }
   format.json { render json: @meeting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Remember that

- **rand(1..1000)** generate random numbers from 2 ->1000
- **rand(1...1000**) generate random numbers from 1 -> 1000